# How do I get certain things removed and printed out in a Dictionary?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on a homework assignment and I cannot figure out how to remove a song from the dictionary and how do i get a function to only print out the artist in the song list?

```
pl=[]
    song ={"song":"Baby","artist":"Justin Bieber","duration":220,"genre":"pop"}

    pl.append(song)

    def printPlaylist(pl):
        for i in range (0,len(pl)):
            play = pl [i]
            print("song-",play["song"])
            print("artist-",play["artist"])
            print("duration-",play["duration"])
            print("genre-",play["genre"])
            print("---")
    print("raw list")
    printPlaylist(pl)

    def addSong(pl,song,artist,duration,genre="pop"):
        pl.append ({"song":title,"artist":singer,"duration":time,"genre":kind})

    def removeSongs(pl,song):
        title = ("Enter a song")
        if song in pl:
            del song[title]
        else:
            print = ("Song not in list")

    def listByArtist(pl):
         listByArtist = sorted(listByArtist,key=pl
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific value of a dictionary, call it by its key:

```
song ={"song":"Baby","artist":"Justin Bieber","duration":220,"genre":"pop"}
artist = song["artist"]
print artist #Justin Bieber
```

And what exactly do you mean by *remove from the dictionary?*

Comment: how do i remove a song from the dictionary. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Do you mean removing `"song":"Baby"` from the dictionary `song`?

Comment: this is exactly what it is asking "Remove songs from the playlist. You will remove all the songs that have the substring passed in song. So if the 
user calls the function with “by” it will for example remove song “Baby”. Print out a message indicating whether 
or not the user successfully removed the song or if the song was not in the playlist."

Answer (score 0):

To remove a song from the LIST (not dictionary) of songs, you need smth like this:

```
def removeSongs(pl, song):
    removed_indices = []
    for ix, s in enumerate(pl):
        if s["song"] == song:
            removed_indices.append(ix)
    for i in removed_indices:
        del pl[i]
    return True if removed_indices else False
```

then you can use it like this:

```
title = raw_input("Enter song title to remove: ")
smth_was_removed = removeSongs(playlist, title)
if not smth_was_removed:
    print("No such song")
else:
    print("All songs with that title were removed")
```

Futhermore, `del` is not meant to be used like that on lists; if you want to delete an item from a list, you need to know its index:

```
>>> a = ["Erik", "John", "Mary"]
>>> del a[1]  # deletes "John"
>>> a
["Erik", "Mary"]
```

on dictionaries, it works like this:

```
>>> x = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> del x["b"]
>>> x
{"a": 1, "c": 3}
```